# jQuery/JavaScript: Auto Number Format

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently, I am using this plugin https://github.com/teamdf/jquery-number to auto-format the number that I entered, but I encountered some problem, when I enter 
999999999999999.99 it will round off to 1,000,000,000,000,000.00, I don't need to round off the number that I entered, I only need to format the number using the comma,
I need the exact numbers that I entered, how can I do it? is there any way?

here is my current code:

```
$(".numeric-total").blur(function () {
     var value = $(this).val();

     value = $.number(value.replace(/,/g, ""), 2);
     $(this).prop('value', value);           
});
```

Comment: It's possible that the string is casted to an actual number and this happens http://floating-point-gui.de/. Try `console.log(999999999999999.99)` and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $(".numeric-total").blur(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            value = value.replace(".", ",");
            value = $.number(value.replace(/,/g, ""), 2);
            alert(value);
            $(this).prop('value', value);
        });
    });
</script>
```